# Iframe- thankyoupage

Tags: html, css, iframe

Hi I have problem with open thankyoupage in new tab.  How I can fix it please ? Because When I use iframe plugin that I must use it only open in iframe window. THANKS 
I have this HTML code :

```
<div id="sideOpt">
    <form method="post" name="email" action="http://www.gogvo.com/subscribe.php">
        <div>
            <input id="sideInput" type="email" name="Email" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='Vložte Vaši Emailovou Adresu';}" onfocus="javascript:this.value=''" value="Vložte Vaši Emailovou Adresu" title="Vložte Vaši Emailovou Adresu">
            <input id="sideSend" type="submit" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="Campaign" value="8e89d34ffa27" />
            <input type="hidden" name="AffiliateName" value="ErikPiovarci" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ThankyouPage" value="http://www.simplemoneysystem.cz/rs/APkKib" />
            <input type="hidden" name="OptIn" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value="Odběratel">
            <input type="hidden" name="AL" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="LS" value="10">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you need a `target` attribute on your `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Add target="_blank" to your form tag.

```
<form method="post" name="email" target="_blank" action="http://www.gogvo.com/subscribe.php">
```